# -[CALayer setFrame:] crash

Tags: ios, swift

I'm receiving this crash report from my app, that seems to occur when scrolling through a `UICollectionView`. It's a crash that happens very rarely, and also gives no clue what piece of code is causing it when I have managed to capture it in Xcode. My `UICollectionView` looks essentially like a `UITableView` with three different types of cells - one with a `UILabel` in, one with a `UIImageView` and `UILabel` in, and one with an `AVPlayer` and `UILabel` in.

This is the crash log:

```
-[__NSArrayM setBounds:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1744478c0

Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x18ecb61c0 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18d6f055c objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x18ecbd278 __methodDescriptionForSelector
3  CoreFoundation                 0x18ecba278 ___forwarding___
4  CoreFoundation                 0x18ebb459c _CF_forwarding_prep_0
5  QuartzCore                     0x191fc625c -[CALayer setFrame:]
6  QuartzCore                     0x191fc2e64 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
7  QuartzCore                     0x191fc2d24 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
8  QuartzCore                     0x191f3f7ec CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*)
9  QuartzCore                     0x191f66c58 CA::Transaction::commit()
10 MediaToolbox                   0x195b5013c playerremote_Invalidate
11 MediaToolbox                   0x195bd5ca4 playerasync_InvalidateOnQueue
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x18db411c0 _dispatch_client_callout
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x18db4f444 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x18db449a8 _dispatch_queue_invoke
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x18db4f940 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x18db5138c _dispatch_root_queue_drain
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x18db510ec _dispatch_worker_thread3
18 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18dd4a2b8 _pthread_wqthread
19 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18dd49da4 start_wqthread
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you set exception breakpoint and add crash method?

Comment: check https://www.natashatherobot.com/xcode-debugging-trick/

Comment: To debug this, run your app with [zombies enabled](http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/devcef23c572).

Answer (score 0):

You can symbolicate the crash report and it will actually load the dump of memory addresses in variables and you can identify the reason of this crash. You must have the DSYM directory of the build on which you are getting this crash as that directory has the reference of the debug symbols which will be required for symbolicating the crash report data.

Comment: So I can symbolicate it so that it loads in to Xcode, and it loads all the threads that were created at the time of the crash.. But how do I "identify the reason of the crash" from it? I can't see any memory addresses

Comment: Yes, when the crash report is symbolicated all the memory addresses, stacks, variables, etc. are loaded and we can debug as we debug the app in normal routine. You can inspect all the objects, variables, arrays etc. and that will help you identify the crash. `-[__NSArrayM setBounds:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1744478c0`. It is evident that array is `nil` when being accessed by `UICollectionView` or `UITableView`

Comment: Where are they loaded though? I can't see anywhere to access the memory addresses or objects!

Comment: I think if you follow the instructions as per the Article below, that will help you understand it better. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html